# TeamCity could not build Unity3D project

Tags: unity-game-engine, teamcity

I am trying to build a simple Unity3D project using TeamCity. The problem is that TeamCity cannot find the scene file and I am getting the following error message:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -batchMode -quit -nographics -projectPath C:\unityProject
[catting log file]
'' is an incorrect path for a scene file. BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.
'' is an incorrect path for a scene file. BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.
```

The [image](http://liortalblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/web.png) shows how I set up the build. When I run the build using command line on computer I have no problem to build the project, just using the TeamCity.
I was thinking if there is a way to add scene file in the editor. I don't want to use "method execution" and run BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer() method.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs, if within your build command `scenes : String[]` parameter there are empty strings `''`.

If you put AutoBuilder Script ([C#](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=AutoBuilder), [JavaScript](https://github.com/geildanke/UNT.autobuilder)) into any `Assets/Editor` folder or subfolder within your project, you can easily call the build script appropriate for your Player OS from `-executeMethod` like this:

```
Unity -buildTarget android -executeMethod "AutoBuilder.PerformAndroidBuild"
```

AutoBuilder does the job to pass the selected scenes automatically like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the paths of the activated scenes from the BuildSettings
 * @return {String[]} BuiltinArray of Strings
 */
function GetScenePaths () {
    var scenes = new Array();

    for(var i : int = 0; i < EditorBuildSettings.scenes.Length; i += 1) {

        /**
         * Only add scene, if it is enabled in the build settings.
         */
        if (EditorBuildSettings.scenes[i].enabled) {
            scenes.Push(EditorBuildSettings.scenes[i].path);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return a builtin array instead of a JavaScript Array
     */
    var builtinArray : String[] = scenes.ToBuiltin(String) as String[];
    return builtinArray;
}
```

You can find AutoBuilder in JavaScript here: https://github.com/geildanke/UNT.autobuilder (I rewrite the great work from the C# AutoBuilder.cs into JavaScript for the ones that prefer JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set an `Execute Method` on your image.  Have you created a static build class that sets up the build pipeline?

For example ([taken directly from docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)):

```
// C# example
using UnityEditor;
class MyEditorScript
{
    static void PerformBuild ()
    {
        string[] scenes = { "Assets/MyScene.unity" };
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, ...);
    }
}
```